# Upload multiple files in same Array - Jquery

Tags: jquery

I try to upload single files and stack them in the same array but every time I do it, Its create a new array with same name , I like to be every time you add new file to record in this array so on submit to submit them all

```
<input type="file" name="file-input" multiple id="file-upload"/>
```

**Jquery**

```
  var fileInput = document.getElementById('file-upload');
  var fileList = [];
  fileInput.addEventListener('change', function (event)
  {
      for (var i = 0; i < this.files.length; i++)
      fileList.push(fileInput.files[i]);
    {
      console.log(fileInput.files)
    }
  });
```

Comment: Your file input does not have the `multiple` attribute set, so it can only “hold”/ select one single file at a time. So your for loop will run only one time each time you select a file as well. Not sure what you mean by _“it open a new array”_ though.

Comment: Why not just use `<input type="file" multiple="true" />`? Then you get this exact behaviour by default, without need for JS

Comment: sorry i forget to add attribute multiple  in the post

i want each time you select/change/add file to stack in same array so if you add 10 single files in one array than u can submit them all
by default each time you select new file old one is deleted

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is this line:

`<input type="file" name="file-input" id="file-upload"/>`.

You have to add multiple so that it can add more than one images.

`<input type="file" name="file-input" id="file-upload" multiple/>`

Also, for loop looks wrong with the brackets.

```
 var fileList = [];

 var fileInput = document.getElementById('file-upload');

 fileInput.addEventListener('change', function (event)
 {

 for (var i = 0; i < fileInput.length; i++)
 {
  fileList.push($('#file-upload')[0].files[i]);
 }

  console.log(fileList);

});
```

Comment: It's probably best to redefine `fileList` as an empty array inside the `change` event too so that it's an exact replication of the file control

Comment: yes i add attribute multiple on input but what about fileList an empty ? i try it 
var var fileList = Array();
but still on every change to create new array with this name isnt record changes in the exist array

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Submit the form?

Comment: im trying each time you add file to stack in array and when you submit the form to submit all files you have been added , if i select 2-3 files together is working fine but when i select them one buy one they dont stack in array and submit only last file added

Comment: Updated Answer.